# Jar signing Java 6 vs Java 8

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner

I have a signed jar. With Java 7/8 my application has no issues. With Java 6 it complains about unsigned entry in jar. I verified the jar using `jarsigner -verify myjar.jar`

Output Java 7, Java8 -> "jar verified"

Output Java 6 -> "jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)"

I tried to build and sign the jar with jdk 6, 7, 8 32/64 bit versions. No change.

Does anyone have an idea what could happen here?

Comment: Are you possibly using an ECDSA signing key&cert? Java6 didn't do ECC out of the box. (And of course you know it's long unsupported and insecure.)

Comment: No. the public key is a RSA 2048 and the signature algorithm of the cert is a SHA256. As far as I know Java 6 should be capable to handle SHA 256. I did some further research and found an earlier version of my app which works with Java 6. This version was signed with a SHA1 Algorithm. Can this be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the issue. The problem is the TSA. We added a timestamp to the signature. Java 6 doesn't seem to be able to handle timestamps from this TSA we used. Solution is either to use a TSA the Java6 client is capable to handle or remove the timestamp.